# Inserir duas checkbox em campos diferentes em mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho este código que cria esta tabela com os dois primeiros campos já preenchido de padrão:

```
<?php
$result_cursos = "SELECT nome,
                         Quarto 

FROM centrodb.utentes

WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' AND nome <> 'CLASSE' AND ativo = '1' ORDER BY nome ASC;";

    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Utente</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Quarto</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Data Registo</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Micção</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Dejecção</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {


$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="45" name= "NomeUtente[]" id= "NomeUtente" value="'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="1" name= "Quarto[]" id= "Quarto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Quarto'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="datetime-local" name= "DataRegisto[]" id= "DataRegisto"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Miccao[]"  value="Realizado"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo1[]" id= "Tipo1" size="30" ></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Dejeccao[]" value="Realizado"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo[]" id= "Tipo" size="30" ></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <select name="Colaborador[]" id="Colaborador">
   <option value="ANA CRISTINA MACHADO FERREIRA">ANA CRISTINA MACHADO FERREIRA</option>
   <option value="ANA PAULA PEREIRA BARBOSA">ANA PAULA PEREIRA BARBOSA</option>
   <option value="ANA PAULA SANTOS FLORES SILVA GONÇALVES">ANA PAULA SANTOS FLORES SILVA GONÇALVES</option>
   <option value="ANABELA OLIVEIRA FERNANDES DE MOURA CAMPOS">ANABELA OLIVEIRA FERNANDES DE MOURA CAMPOS</option>
   <option value="CLARINDA ROSA GONÇALVES MOREIRA FERNANDES">CLARINDA ROSA GONÇALVES MOREIRA FERNANDES</option>
   <option value="EUNICE MIRIAM MARTINS AZEVEDO">EUNICE MIRIAM MARTINS AZEVEDO</option>
   <option value="FERNANDA ALMEIDA">FERNANDA ALMEIDA</option>
   <option value="FERNANDA MARIA VASQUES MENDONÇA PEREIRA">FERNANDA MARIA VASQUES MENDONÇA PEREIRA</option>
   <option value="FLORINDA MARIA SANTOS CARDOSO DA COSTA PINTO">FLORINDA MARIA SANTOS CARDOSO DA COSTA PINTO</option>
   <option value="GEORGINA MARIA MATOS DE CARVALHO ARAÚJO">GEORGINA MARIA MATOS DE CARVALHO ARAÚJO</option>
   <option value="ISABEL MARIA GONÇALVES RODRIGUES GRAÇA">ISABEL MARIA GONÇALVES RODRIGUES GRAÇA</option>
   <option value="ISABEL MARIA MATOS MEIRELES BARROS BARGE">ISABEL MARIA MATOS MEIRELES BARROS BARGE</option> 
   <option value="JOANA RAQUEL COSTA LOPES">JOANA RAQUEL COSTA LOPES</option>
   <option value="LUISA DA CONCEIÇÃO COELHO DE ALMEIDA">LUISA DA CONCEIÇÃO COELHO DE ALMEIDA</option>
   <option value="MARIA ALICE SANTOS MAIA">MARIA ALICE SANTOS MAIA</option>
   <option value="MARIA BERNADETE MONTEIRO MOREIRA">MARIA BERNADETE MONTEIRO MOREIRA</option>
   <option value="MARIA CONCEIÇÃO ALMEIDA MARTINHO DIAS">MARIA CONCEIÇÃO ALMEIDA MARTINHO DIAS</option>
   <option value="MARIA DE JESUS BENTO MENDES">MARIA DE JESUS BENTO MENDES</option>
   <option value="MARIA HELENA TEIXEIRA FERREIRINHA">MARIA HELENA TEIXEIRA FERREIRINHA</option> 
   <option value="MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA">MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA</option>
   <option value="MARIA MANUELA MARTINS MORENO">MARIA MANUELA MARTINS MORENO</option>
   <option value="MONICA ALEXANDRA HORA GOMES MEDEIROS">MONICA ALEXANDRA HORA GOMES MEDEIROS</option>
   <option value="MÁRIO ANTÓNIO MOREIRA FERREIRA">MÁRIO ANTÓNIO MOREIRA FERREIRA</option>
   <option value="PATRÍCIA ALEXANDRA SILVA INÁCIO">PATRÍCIA ALEXANDRA SILVA INÁCIO</option>   
   <option value="PAULA CRISTINA RIBEIRO DA SILVA RODRIGUES">PAULA CRISTINA RIBEIRO DA SILVA RODRIGUES</option>
   <option value="PAULA MARIA RODRIGUES DA SILVA">PAULA MARIA RODRIGUES DA SILVA</option>
   <option value="PEDRO MONTEIRO">PEDRO MONTEIRO</option>
   <option value="SILVIA MANUELA DA SILVA BORGES">SILVIA MANUELA DA SILVA BORGES</option>  
</select></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
    }
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
echo $tabela1;   

echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

?>
```

Depois de criar a tabela, tenho este código para inserir na tabela da base de dados. Só pode inserir a linha da tabela que eu preencher.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) {
    $utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'][$i];
    $quarto = $_POST['Quarto'][$i];
    $data = $_POST['DataRegisto'][$i];
    $miccao = $_POST['Miccao'][$i];
    $tipo1 = $_POST['Tipo1'][$i];
    $dejeccao = $_POST['Dejeccao'][$i];
    $tipo = $_POST['Tipo'][$i];
    $colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$miccao', '$tipo1', '$dejeccao', '$tipo', '$colaborador')";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}
}
?>
```

O problema é que quando preencho só uma checkbox em cada linha como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele insere oos valores da checkbox na mesma linha e não pode. Na primeira só devia inserir o valor da checkbox da micção e na segunda o valor da checkbox da dejecção.
Mostro como estaá a preencher erradamente na tabela da base de dados na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não, o meucódigo está todo aqui. O problema é que o código só faz o registo das checkbox correto na primeira  linha da tabela que mostro ao utilizador. Depois dessa linha ou marco as duas checkbox ou então insere as duas colunas em branco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comportamento do input type=”checkbox” do html é enviar para o server-side apenas os checkboxes marcados

**Da forma que você está fazendo ao enviar o formulário:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**vai retornar**

```
Array ( [0] => ABEL DE FIGUEIREDO PINTO [1] => ADELINO VALE LOUREIRO ) 
Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => 30 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2018-03-31T15:00 [1] => 2018-03-31T15:00 ) 
Array ( [0] => Realizado )  //faltando [1]
Array ( [0] => Realizado )  //faltando [1]
Array ( [0] => MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA [1] => MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA )
```

Portanto ao realizar o loop for as sql serão:

**para `$i=0`**

```
INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) 
VALUES ('ABEL DE FIGUEIREDO PINTO', '16', '2018-03-31T15:00', 'Realizado', '', 'Realizado', '', 'MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA')
```

**para `$i=1`**

```
INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) 
VALUES ('ADELINO VALE LOUREIRO', '30', '2018-03-31T15:00', '', '', '', '', 'MARIA JOSÉ NOGUEIRA RODRIGUES PEREIRA')
```

### Você obterá sucesso dessa forma

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$NomeUtente = $_POST['NomeUtente'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) {
    $utente = $NomeUtente[$i];
    $quarto = $_POST['Quarto'][$i];
    $data = $_POST['DataRegisto'][$i];
    $miccao = $_POST['Miccao'][$i];
    $tipo1 = $_POST['Tipo1'][$i];
    $dejeccao = $_POST['Dejeccao'][$i];
    $tipo = $_POST['Tipo'][$i];
    $colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i];
    ..............................
```

**e no formulário**

no while incremente um contador concatenando o `$j` exceto em NomeUtente[]

```
$j=0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="45" name= "NomeUtente[]" id= "NomeUtente" value="'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="1" name= "Quarto['.$j.']" id= "Quarto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Quarto'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="datetime-local" name= "DataRegisto['.$j.']" id= "DataRegisto"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Miccao['.$j.']" value="Realizado"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo1['.$j.']" id= "Tipo1" size="30" ></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Dejeccao['.$j.']" value="Realizado"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo['.$j.']" id= "Tipo" size="30" ></td>';


$tabela1 .= '<td> <select name="Colaborador['.$j.']" id="Colaborador">
....................
....................

$j++;
}
```